# Change the font and background for console output (PySimpleGUI)

Tags: python, pysimplegui

I'm trying to change the font and background for my console output in my PySimpleGUI script for a more console look and feel. I can seem to figure out how to though, I've tried to add `background_color='hex code`, along with `font='font name'`. Neither of those have worked for me.

My Code:

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import subprocess
import os
import sys

def runCommand(cmd, timeout=None, window=None):
    p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    output = ''
    for line in p.stdout:
        line = line.decode(errors='replace' if (sys.version_info) < (3, 5) else 'backslashreplace').rstrip()
        output += line
        print(line)
        window.Refresh() if window else None
        retval = p.wait(timeout)
    return (retval, output)                         

def main():
    f = open(r'C:/Users/{}/AppData/Roaming/spicetify/config-xpui.ini'.format(user))
    config = f.read()
    layout = [
        [sg.Im('src/spicetify-full.png')],
        [sg.T('Spicetify Config File:')],
        [sg.Multiline(config, size=(82, 10))],
        [sg.B('Apps'), sg.B('Themes'), sg.B('Extensions'), sg.B('Apply'), sg.B('Backup'), sg.B('Restore'), sg.Button('Install CLI'), sg.B('Exit')],
        [sg.T('Console Input: '), sg.In(key='_IN_', size=(52)),sg.B('Send Command')],
        [sg.Output(size=(82,10))]
    ]
    window = sg.Window('Spicetify', 
                        layout, 
                        modal=False,
                        icon=r'src\spicetify-logo.ico',
                        use_ttk_buttons=True,
                        ttk_theme=ttk_style
                        )
    while True:
        event, values = window.read()
        if event == 'Apps':
            window.hide()
            Apps()
        if event == 'Themes':
            window.hide()
            Themes()
        if event == 'Extensions':
            window.hide()
            Extensions()
        if event == 'Apply':
            os.system('spicetify apply')
            sg.popup('Spicetify Config Applied!',
                     icon=r'src\spicetify-logo.ico',)
        if event == 'Backup':
            os.system('spicetify backup')
            sg.popup('Spicetify Backed Up!',
                     icon=r'src\spicetify-logo.ico')
        if event == 'Restore':
            os.system('spicetify restore')
            sg.popup('Spotify Restored!',
                     icon=r'src\spicetify-logo.ico')
        if event == 'Install CLI':
            subprocess.run("iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spicetify/spicetify-cli/master/install.ps1 | iex", shell=True ,capture_output=True,text=True)
            subprocess.run("iwr -useb https://raw.githubusercontent.com/spicetify/spicetify-marketplace/main/resources/install.ps1 | iex", shell=True ,capture_output=True,text=True)
        if event == 'Exit':
            return
        if event == 'Send Command':
            runCommand(cmd=values['_IN_'], window=window)
        if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
            return
    window.close()

main()
```

Can anyone possible help me change the font and background of the Output screen?